# Open A Modal on Link Press if User is Not Logged in

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a download link on a website and am trying to keep the user on the page if he/she is not logged in. I need to display a bootstrap modal via php echo, but only if the user is not logged in.

Here is the question:

How do I display the modal when a link is clicked only if the user is **NOT** logged in? I don't mind a JS onclick event either.

```
<?php
  if ( ! $logged_in){
   echo '<CODE-FOR-MY-MODAL>';
 }
?>
```

**EDIT:**

The link also needs to be disabled if the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
  if ( ! $logged_in){
   echo '<script>var loggedin = false; </script>';
 }
?>
```

Then in the click handler callback, you check the `loggedin` variable and decide whether to display the modal.

Example in jQuery

```
$('.link').click(function(){

if(!loggedin){
// show modal
}

});
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the discussion in comments, here are two fiddles one showing the prevent behaviour when the user is not logged in and another is working example of bootstrap modal integration.

http://jsfiddle.net/p8tfLbzs/

http://jsfiddle.net/p8tfLbzs/1

Comment: As far as html goes. I  think I would do: `<a class="link" href="link.html">link</a>`  is this correct? Also, I believe the jQuery  should be `!logged_in` instead of `!loggedin` please clarify the html code I would use, i'm not very good with this. Finally, please check my edit.

Comment: See the variable $logged_in and var loggedin are different one is from php and another from javascript. So in jQuery it should be !loggedin. And yes you are right about the link. You can remove the href from there or use a button instead. I think using a button would be appropriate for this. <button class="link">Link</button>

Comment: Will the code you provided block the download if the user is not logged in?

Comment: if you have a link that has a default action, for example <a class="link" href="DOWNLOAD LINK">link</a>,  what you can do is you can prevent that from happening by using $('.link').click(function(e){

if(!loggedin){
e.preventDefault();
// show modal
}

});

Comment: One more thing, if you want the user to prevent from downloading, this method is not secure at all. As the user can still copy the download link and visit it manually.

Comment: This is only to keep honest people honest. I am grateful for your solution!

Comment: Here is a link to a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p8tfLbzs/

Try changing the value of loggedin variable to true and run the fiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157453/discussion-between-crimson-501-and-faisal-umair).